# GCC -O3 generates strange assembly for std::uninitialized_default_construct

Tags: c++, gcc, assembly, optimization, x86-64

I'm looking at the assembly generated by GCC 9.1 for the new (C++17) function std::uninitialized_default_construct. In most cases (MSVC, Clang, even older GCC) it's what you would expect: a loop with calling (or inlining) the default constructor of the type T.

For some reason, the GCC from 7 to current run with -03 generates assembly that I do not fully understand. Especially the part that looks like hashing at the beginning.

I'm compiling with "-O3 -std=c++17 -fno-stack-protector -fno-exceptions -fomit-frame-pointer -fno-unroll-loops". Am I missing something here?

Tested the same code on various compilers. None behaves this strangely. There's no explanation I could find for the hashing thing.

Test code (run via godbolt.org):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <memory>
#include <string>
#include <stdio.h>

struct Vector3 {
    float x=0,y=0,z=0; 
};

template< typename T >
static int init(T* mem, size_t len)
{
    std::uninitialized_default_construct(mem, mem+len);     
    return 0;
}

template< typename T >
static int init2(T* mem, size_t len)
{
    auto end = mem + len;
    while (mem < end)
        new (mem++) T();
    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    Vector3 mem[100];
    auto funcPtr = (argc > 2) ? &init<Vector3> : &init2<Vector3>;

    if (0 != funcPtr(mem, (int)atoi(argv[1])))
        return -1;
    printf("%f\n", mem[0].x);
    return 0;
}
```

Generated disassembly for function "init" (brace yourself):

```
int init<Vector3>(Vector3*, unsigned long):
        lea     rax, [rsi+rsi*2]
        lea     rcx, [rdi+rax*4]
        cmp     rcx, rdi
        je      .L2
        movabs  rsi, 3074457345618258603
        mov     rdx, rcx
        mov     rax, rdi
        sub     rdx, rdi
        sub     rdx, 12
        shr     rdx, 2
        imul    rdx, rsi
        movabs  rsi, 4611686018427387903
        and     rdx, rsi
        lea     rsi, [rdx+1]
        cmp     rdx, 2
        jbe     .L3
        mov     rdx, rsi
        pxor    xmm0, xmm0
        shr     rdx, 2
        lea     rdx, [rdx+rdx*2]
        sal     rdx, 4
        add     rdx, rdi
.L4:
        movups  XMMWORD PTR [rax], xmm0
        add     rax, 48
        movups  XMMWORD PTR [rax-32], xmm0
        movups  XMMWORD PTR [rax-16], xmm0
        cmp     rax, rdx
        jne     .L4
        mov     rax, rsi
        and     rax, -4
        lea     rdx, [rax+rax*2]
        lea     rdi, [rdi+rdx*4]
        cmp     rsi, rax
        je      .L2
.L3:
        lea     rax, [rdi+12]
        mov     QWORD PTR [rdi], 0
        mov     DWORD PTR [rdi+8], 0x00000000
        cmp     rcx, rax
        je      .L2
        lea     rax, [rdi+24]
        mov     QWORD PTR [rdi+12], 0
        mov     DWORD PTR [rdi+20], 0x00000000
        cmp     rcx, rax
        je      .L2
        mov     QWORD PTR [rdi+24], 0
        mov     DWORD PTR [rdi+32], 0x00000000
.L2:
        xor     eax, eax
        ret
```

For comparison, this is what MSVC generates for the same code:

```
int init<Vector3>(Vector3 *,unsigned __int64) PROC         ; init<Vector3>, COMDAT
        lea     rax, QWORD PTR [rdx+rdx*2]
        lea     rdx, QWORD PTR [rcx+rax*4]
        xor     eax, eax
        cmp     rcx, rdx
        je      SHORT $LN5@init
        npad    1
$LL6@init:
        mov     QWORD PTR [rcx], rax
        mov     DWORD PTR [rcx+8], eax
        add     rcx, 12
        cmp     rcx, rdx
        jne     SHORT $LL6@init
$LN5@init:
        ret     0
```

Is there a way to make GCC behave properly?

Comment: It has simply vectorized the fill so it can do 48 bytes in one iteration. Longer assembly code doesn't necessarily mean slower. In this case I would have expected a simple `rep stosd` to be both small and efficient.

Comment: Yeah, that part looks fine (although I'm still surprised that the loop was vectorized, even though the -fno-unroll-loops was specified). What about the part around beginning of the function, any idea what that is ?

Comment: That's a magic number division to calculate number of iterations.

Comment: Didn't expect that. But yeah, after simplifying it to more readable format it makes sense:

`
rdx = (((count*12 - 12) / 2) * 0x2AAAAAAAAAAAAAAB) & 0x3FFFFFFFFFFFFFFF; 
if (rdx <= 2) goto...;
`
I'm curious to test when this extra work starts to pay off as no other compiler decided to unroll that loop. @Jester: thanks for the help!

Comment: Actually. I found the reason for this excessive overgrow of assembly: size_t as the count. Changing this to unsigned int produces much more well-behaved assembly.

Comment: no-unroll-loops is the default unless you enable PGO (so GCC knows which loops are hot enough to deserve it).  It doesn't disable vectorization, it just means that loops will do one vector per iteration.  Use `-fno-tree-vectorize` if you want to disable vectorization as well.  `memset` / zero-fill inline expansion is separate from both of those, though, but IDK why you ended up with an unroll of 3 vectors instead of some other number.  Maybe related to the 3 struct members.  `rep stos` has significant startup overhead so it's not great for small sizes (which are often common).